# How find find offset of a function using gdb?

Tags: gdb, dwarf

I have a shared object file that has DWARF info. I want to find the offset of a function. My stack trace is in the format `mangledFuncName + 0x123`. I want to find the line of code for the corresponding frame. Ideally I'd like to build some sort of mapping between all offsets of a .so file and the filename/linenumber for the offset/range of offsets. Is this possible to do with gdb?

Answer (score 5):

```
gdb <so or file loading so>
(gdb) b main
(gdb) run
(gdb) p youfun
(gdb) info line *(0xabcdef+0xab)
(gdb) list *(0xabcdef+0xab)
(gdb) info symbol 0xabcdef
(gdb) b *(0xabcdef+0xab)
```

- line 2 and 3 are there to make the `.so` file load.
  It is not needed if you have the debug info loaded already
  (`file` or as gdb argument).
- line 4 will show the address of the function
- replace `0xabcdef` with the address of the function and `0xab` with the offset

Answer (score 3):

> I want to find the offset of a function.

```
readelf -Ws foo.so | egrep ' function\W'
```

For example:

```
readelf -Ws /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | egrep ' open\W'
  1782: 00000000000eb430   294 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT   14 open@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

The value of `open` is `0xeb430`

> My stack trace is in the format mangledFuncName + 0x123. I want to find the line of code for the corresponding frame

The easiest solution is to compute actual address (add `0x123` to the address of `mangledFuncName` extracted above), and use `addr2line -fe foo.so $addr`

For example, mapping `open+0x123` to source file/line yields:

```
addr2line -fe /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 0xeb483
__libc_open64
/build/glibc-oCLvUT/glibc-2.29/io/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/open64.c:48 (discriminator 1)
```